# Integrate $\int_0^\infty \frac x{ \sec x\cosh x \>+\>1}dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, contour-integration, trigonometric-integrals

I am interested in whether it is possible to evaluate the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac x{ \sec x\cosh x +1}dx$$
For reference, the analogous integral below is manageable
$$\int_0^\infty \frac 1{ \sec x\cosh x +1}dx= -\pi \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \text{csch}\>k\pi
$$
which can be evaluated with the residues in the upper-half plane given the symmetry. But a similar approach for the integral in question is not applicable due to the odd integrand. I would like to know of any other  possibilities.

Comment: FWIW, the numerical value is $-0.31686699596869283170539849855453950746299041699298143060323465277828
18440962839489141401037513219271\dots$

Comment: If **you** ask a question about integrals, I bet that the problem is very, very difficult. Cheers :-)

Comment: Could somebody tell me how to calculate the residues? I am not getting $\operatorname{csch}$, though I know it's correct for I checked WA.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - I’m still learning…

Comment: May be you are but be sure that I shall never compete with you when the are antiderivatives or integrals. of this kind (plus many other). Cheers :-)

Comment: Equivalent to $-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+k} \frac{n k}{(n^2+k^2)^2}$ but I’m not sure this has a closed-form…

Comment: @YiFan: I'm getting $0.3168669959\cdots27782818440962839\color{red}{56160287979596429}\cdots$

Comment: @metamorphy Oops, I accidentally forgot to set the precision goal correctly when asking Mathematica to calculate it. Your value is right.

Comment: @KStarGamer - Guess there is no elementary expression for the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}  k}{(n^2+k^2)^2}$

Comment: I'm sure you are aware, but we can have $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1} \sin (x)}{\cos (x)+\cosh (x)} \, dx = 2^{1-3s/2} (2^s-2) \Gamma (s)\sin (\pi s/4) \zeta(s)$$ but having $\cos (x)$ on the numerator instead complicates things.

Comment: Via Ramanujan's master theorem, one has that $$\frac{\sin (x)}{\cos (x)+\cosh (x)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{n!} \cdot 2^{1+n/2} (2^{n+1}-1)\sin(\pi n/4)\zeta(-n)$$ if one could find a similar series for $\frac{\cos (x)}{\cosh(x)+\cos (x)}$ or something like $\frac{\sin (x+\pi/4)}{\cos (x)+\cosh (x)}$ through $\cos (x)=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4)-\sin (x)$ then the problem is solved. Some hope: $$\frac{\cos(x)+e^{-x}}{\cos (x)+\cosh (x)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n}{n!} \cdot 2^{1+n/2} (2^{n+1}-1)\cos(\pi n/4)\zeta(-n)$$

Comment: I made a typo on the final line of the above as it should be $(1-2^{n+1})$ on the RHS i.e off by a sign. An interesting consequence of the above that may be relevant is $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sec (x) \cosh (x)+1} \, dx = -\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x e^{-x}}{ \cosh (x) + \cos (x)} \, dx$$

Comment: @KStarGamer   That last identity can also be derived by integrating the function $$\frac{z e^{iz}}{\cosh z + \cos z}$$ around the contour $[0, R] \cup R e^{i[0, \pi/2]} \cup i [R,0] $ , and then letting $R \to \infty$.

Comment: @Quanto any progress on this integral??

Answer (score 4):

*This is not an answer but, may be, it could give you some ideas.*

Suppose that we write

$$\frac{x}{\sec (x) \cosh (x)+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\, x \Big[\cos (x)\, \text{sech}(x)\Big]^{n+1}$$
The antiderivative
$$J_n=\int x \Big[\cos (x)\, \text{sech}(x)\Big]^{n+1}\,dx$$ express as nasty combinations of hypergeometric functions but the definite integrals
$$K_n=\int_0^\infty x \Big[\cos (x)\, \text{sech}(x)\Big]^{n+1}\,dx$$ do not seem to be too bad in terms of polygamma functions with complex arguments.
$$K_0=\frac{1}{16} \left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1-i}{4}\right)+\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1+i}{4}\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{3-i}{4}\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{3+i}{4}\right)\right)$$
$$K_1=\frac{\log (2)}{2}+\frac {\Delta_1} {16}$$
$$\Delta_1=-2 \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1-i}{2}\right)-2 \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)+2 \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{2-i}{2}\right)+2 \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{2+i}{2}\right)+i
   \left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1-i}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{2-i}{2}\right)+\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{2+i}{2}\right)\right)$$ The next ones become relly too long to be typed but they do not present specific problems.

What I am afraid is that the convergence will be extremely slow.

**Edit**

Using what @KStarGamer wrote in comment
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac x{ \sec (x)\cosh (x) +1}\,dx=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+k} \frac{n k}{(n^2+k^2)^2}$$
$$I=\frac i 8 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1-i n}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1+i n}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(1)}\left(-\frac{i
   n}{2}\right)+\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{i n}{2}\right)\right)$$

It could be worth to notice that, if
$$a_n=\frac i 8 (-1)^{n+1}\left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1-i n}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1+i n}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(1)}\left(-\frac{i
   n}{2}\right)+\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{i n}{2}\right)\right)$$

$$a_n=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left|\left(1-2^{2 k+2}\right) B_{2 k+2}\right|\, n^{-(2k+3)}$$

Comment: By the way, the sum can be simplified to be $$I=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2} \left(\psi^{(1)} \left(\frac{(1-i)(1+k)}{2}\right)-\psi^{(1)}\left(-\frac{(1+i)(i+k)}{2}\right)\right)$$ reducing the number of trigamma terms.

Comment: @KStarGamer. Much better ! Thank you.